# C program to convert string to integer and solve them algebraically

Tags: c, string, math, integer

I want to take a string consisting only of numbers and arithmetic operators. Then solve them algebraically. e.g. User input as string = "45 - 98 + 656" and get the output as "603" an integer.
Here's my code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){

    scanf(%s, &S);
    int sum = 0;
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(S); i++) {
        if (S[i] == ' ') {
            continue;
        } else
        if (S[i] != ' ') {
            if (isdigit(S[i])) {
                a = atoi(&S[i]);
            } else
            if (!isdigit(S[i])) {
                if (S[i] == '+') {                    
                    S[i] = S[i + 1];
                    sum = (sum + a);
                } else
                if (S[i] == '-') {        
                    S[i] = S[i + 1];
                    sum = (sum - a); 
                } else {
                    sum = a;
                }
            }
        }                                                                            
    } 
    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to add those sequence of number in a string. Just like we do it in a calculator.

Comment: That's not a question

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: @ManishMishra A post without a question attracts down-votes.  A post with a clear question attracts up-votes.  Your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors.

- You forgot the `"` around `%s`
- you did not declare `S`

Here is a simpler solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[200];

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        long sum = 0;

        /* remove all white space */
        for (int i = j = 0, len = strlen(buf); i <= len; i++) {
            if (!isspace((unsigned char)buf[i]))
                buf[j++] = buf[i];
        }
        /* parse the expression */
        for (char *p = buf, *q;;) {
            long a = strtol(p, &q, 10);
            if (p == q) {
                break;
            } else {
                sum += a;
                p = q;
            }
        }
        printf("sum = %ld\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you handle the operators ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I only support `+` and `-`: removing the spaces converts the expression into a sequence of numbers each preceded by a `+` or `-` sign. converting each number with `strtol()` gives a positive or negative value and updated `q` to point to the next number. Adding the parsed number to the sum is all that's needed. Supporting more operators requires a more elaborate method with a stack or recursion.

Comment: sorry, I missed that `strtol` handles the signs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: `strtol()` handles initial white space and an optional sign, but not spaces after the sign, which is why I remove all spaces from the string.

Answer (score 1):

This (unusual) solution should do the trick. It works strictly left-to-right:

```
sum= 0
number= 0
op= '+'
while get(character)
  case character of
    digit: case op of
             '+': sum-= number; number= 10 * number + character; sum+= number
             '-': sum+= number; number= 10 * number + character; sum-= number
    '+', '-': number= 0; op= character
```

And now a slightly obfuscated, but very efficient C translation:

```
char* c= "45 - 98 + 656";
int s= 0, n= 0, d, p= 1;
for ( ; d= *c - '0', *c; c++)
    if ((unsigned)d <= 9) { s-= n; n= 10 * n + p * d; s+= n; }
    else if (*c != ' ') { n= 0; p= *c == '+' ? 1 : -1; }
printf("s = %d\n", s);
```

Prints out `603`, as should.

Comment: Very *unusual* C code indeed ;)

Comment: A worthy candidate for  [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Looking this code I see some error,  after `atoi()` you have to increment the index according to number size (Eg "656" is 3 chars long).
Even after this fix this algorithm is wrong because you are executing the operation too early.
I mean, in your example, this algorithm compute -45+98 and do not compute 656.
Moreover `S[i]=S[i+1];` is useless an so .. Wrong

Comment: So, how do I actually do it? I mean, how can I add all those numbers without knowing how long is the number?

Comment: Simpler way is to use this:
`sz=sprintf(tmp,"%d",a);`